# Port forwarding problem using Traefik and docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, proxy, port, reverse-proxy, traefik

I want the next port forwarding:

`http://traefik.service.localhost/` -> `Traefik UI`

`http://api.service.localhost/` -> `'Hello-Word' page from api-service`

Here is my attempt to create appropriate **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.4
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    command: 
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=pred-network
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - pred-network


  api-service:
    image: x86_64/prediction-service:0.8.1
    container_name: api-service
    environment:
      SERVING_SERVICE: model-service
    expose:
      - 80
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.api-service.rule=Host(`api.service.localhost`)
    networks:
      - pred-network

networks:
  pred-network:
```

I am getting the following:

`http://traefik.service.localhost/` -> `HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.`

`http://api.service.localhost/` -> `HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.`

The only link that actually works:

`http://api.service.localhost:8080/` -> `Traefik UI`

If I would include:

```
ports:
  - "8070:80"
```

into **api-service** part of **docker-compose.yml** I could access my 'Hello-Word':
`http://localhost:8070/` -> `"Hello-Word"`
In this case it not get routed through Traefik but directly through **api-service**. Is it possible to do it over Traefik?

Answer (score 1):

To have a service routed by traefik with docker, you should have labels. Traefik will fetch those labels in order to know how to do routing.

Thus, to have request of `api.service.localhost` routed to your api service, you should have the label that define the corresponding [rule](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#rule):

```
traefik.http.routers.service.rule=Host(`api.service.localhost`)
```

As for the label of Traefik, you should have two labels:

```
traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.service.localhost`)
traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal
```

Beside those traefik labels, you should tell traefik to expose the dashboard using a specific service by adding this configuration: [`--api.dashboard`](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/operations/dashboard/#secure-mode) (More help to expose the dashboard [here](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/operations/dashboard/#dashboard-router-rule)).

Note, if your api service uses another port than the one by default, you could add this label:

```
traefik.http.services.service.loadbalancer.server.port=80
```

Ps, do not expose twice the port 80, you only need to expose it for the traefik container.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I updated docker-compose.yml according your recommendations but still getting HTTP Error 404

Comment: can you show your updated docker-compose ?

Comment: Here's a working example for you : https://pastebin.com/59t0nRsH

And please refrain from using `--api.insecure=true`, this is *insecure* !